# Is it appropriate to remove outdated info from this popular historical article?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Encountered this article today:

[Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

It discusses how to parse and serialize JSON, and references [this article by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) written in May of 2009, as a reference for using json2.js. While the information in the article is (arguably) partially relevant, it's extremely dated.

I'd like to propose the following edits to it. **Are these suitable edits for SO, and is this sufficient justification to edit the current answer?**

1. Reposition the details about native implementation to the top of the answer, moving the link to json2.js below
2. Remove the quote and reference to John Resig's article.

E.g.:

---

**For modern browsers:**

To convert an object to a JSON string, use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var json_text = JSON.stringify(your_object, null, 2);
```

To convert a string to JSON object, use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var your_object = JSON.parse(json_text);
```

**For legacy browsers:**

While [Newer browsers](http://caniuse.com/json) support the [JSON object](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.12) natively, older ones do not. One workaround is to use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), which gracefully falls back `eval()` on older browsers, while another is to implement [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Comment: I would only leave a comment because that answer is so heavily upvoted and add a new answer, if that is still valid for the question, to cover the preferred implementation in the current timeframe.

Comment: With outdated answers always remember people on legacy systems. Add new information but don't remove the old

Comment: I think my biggest concern was the quote and link back to the old article (which in turn actually includes dead links). It has no bearing anymore on the relevance of the answer, no?

Comment: Made a minor adjustment to my proposal to show the difference between modern/legacy usage.